# Getting Facebook Conversion Number And Conversion Value From Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get Facebook Conversion and Conversion Value Using the Facebook API. The result i am getting is this :

```
 actions: [
            {
               action_type: "onsite_conversion.post_save",
               value: "29"
            },
            {
               action_type: "like",
               value: "1"
            },
            {
               action_type: "link_click",
               value: "1594"
            },
            {
               action_type: "post",
               value: "12"
            },
            {
               action_type: "post_reaction",
               value: "168"
            },
            {
               action_type: "landing_page_view",
               value: "1290"
            },
            {
               action_type: "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_add_payment_info",
               value: "19"
            },
            {
               action_type: "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_add_to_cart",
               value: "96"
            },
            {
               action_type: "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_initiate_checkout",
               value: "14"
            },
            {
               action_type: "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase",
               value: "1"
            },
            {
               action_type: "post_engagement",
               value: "1803"
            },
            {
               action_type: "page_engagement",
               value: "1804"
            },
            {
               action_type: "add_payment_info",
               value: "19"
            },
            {
               action_type: "omni_add_to_cart",
               value: "96"
            },
            {
               action_type: "omni_initiated_checkout",
               value: "14"
            },
            {
               action_type: "omni_purchase",
               value: "1"
            },
            {
               action_type: "add_to_cart",
               value: "96"
            },
            {
               action_type: "initiate_checkout",
               value: "14"
            },
            {
               action_type: "purchase",
               value: "1"
            }
         ],
```

Is there a way I can only get purchase number and purchase conversion value instead of this long array or a syntax where I can get specific values only. I checked the facebook api parameters website but there is no documentation of the things i need. I even checked other post on stack overflow but I didn't find anything about this.

Comment: What exact endpoint are you using there? Can you link to the documentation, please?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters/v15.0

I am trying to get conversions but i am not getting anything from it. So i am using actions with action breakdown as action_type